# Knowing if router is actually working as bridge?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, bridge, wireless-bridge

I recently purchased a `Netgear R6300 router` and by following this [NetGear link](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20831/~/how-to-set-up-bridge-mode-on-r6300,-r6250-%26-r6200%3F?cid=wmt_netgear_organic), I was able to follow all the steps to set it as `Bridge mode`. In theory, the netgear router should now be picking up the signal from the `trendnet` router that's already wirelessly picking up the signal from my modem.

Once I followed all the steps, the router rebooted. The weird thing is that the Netgear doesn't show up anymore in the available connections; only the `trendnet` is displayed and available, so I select it and connect.

So my question is: how do I know if the `netgear` router (set as bridge) is actually picking up the signal from the router connected to the modem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you connect to the R6300 over a LAN connection?

Comment: Do you perhaps expect the Netgear router to work like a repeater?

Comment: @DanielB, I guess so. I want it to amplify the signal.

Comment: @Ramhound, it's just not possible due to the layout of the apartment.

Comment: You asked how can you tell if its bridge mode.  You connect a PC to the LAN port, that is how you tell, that is the only way to tell.  You can always move the R6300, it will save its configuration, and you can move it back after you are done.

Comment: So what exactly are the instructions in the netgear link for?

Comment: From what I understand, the netgear router as bridge will pick up the signal from the router that's transmitting the internet signal wirelessly. That way, a device will able to connect to the netgear router because the trendnet router (with the internet signal) is too far away.

Comment: It sounds like you actually have three routers on your network. If your "modem" has a wireless capability, it's likely also a router. It's not clear what you already have setup and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bridged mode doesn't do what you think it does: It provides a bridge between a wireless network (where it acts as a client) and wired network (via its LAN ports). It's for connecting wired-only devices to a wireless network (so that they are in the same broadcast domain, hence "bridged"). It does *not necessarily* work as a repeater. In theory, it could, but nothing in the guide you linked to indicates it would.

So basically it's the wrong device for your use case. If you can, return it, and get a wireless repeater. They're usually much more compact, too. If you can't return it, sell it on eBay or whatever.

Whether you'll be satisfied with generic repeater performance is yet another question, I'm experiencing frequent intermittent connectivity problems with my Android Tablet (but not on other devices, like my Android phone). At my parents' home, I set up a proprietary WPA2 WDS network with two TP-Link routers, it works *much* better.